# Реализация решения задачи с одномерным массивом Assembler

Tags: c++, массивы, ассемблер

С помощью ассемблерной вставки в C++ надо реализовать следующую задачу:
**В массиве из 10 чисел обнулить все отрицательные элементы, если
сумма их модулей меньше суммы положительных элементов.**
Написал такой код, но результат не радует... Почему то меняется только первый элемент массива на выводе, и то выдает степени двойки либо 0. Хотелось бы, чтобы кто-нибудь указал на ошибки и помог с реализацией. :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

void fillArray(int*, int);
void showArray(int*, int);

int main() {
    const int n = 10;
    int a[n];
    fillArray(a, n);
    __asm {
            mov ecx, n
            lea edi, a
            mov esi, edi
            mov ebx, 0
            mov edx, 0

            check:
            mov eax, [esi]
            add esi, 1
            cmp eax, 0
            jl sum_minus
            jpe sum_plus

            sum_minus :
            add ebx, eax
            cmp esi, 10
            jl check
            jpe modul

            sum_plus :
            add edx, eax
            cmp esi, 10
            jl check
            jpe modul

            modul :
            neg ebx
            cmp ebx, edx
            jl zero_check

            zero_check :
            mov eax, [edi]
            cmp eax, 0
            jl zero_make
            jpe plus_const

            zero_make :
            mov [edi], 0
            cmp edi, 10
            jl go
            jpe finish

            go :
            add edi, 1
            jmp zero_check

            plus_const :
            mov [edi], eax
            cmp edi, 10
            jl go
            jpe finish

            finish :
    }
    cout << "New array:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        cout << a[i] << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}

void fillArray(int* a, int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        cout << "Enter the " << i + 1 << " array element..." << endl;
        cin >> a[i];
    }
    cout << "Your array: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        cout << a[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто аккуратненько расписать, и никаких проблем...

```
int main()
{
    const int n = 10;
    int a[n];
    fillArray(a, n);

    int ng = 0, ps = 0;

    __asm {
        mov ecx, n
    loop1:
        mov eax, [a + ecx*4 - 4]
        cmp eax, 0
        jge next1
        neg eax
        add ng, eax
        jmp next2
    next1:
        add ps, eax
    next2:
        loop loop1
        mov eax, ng
        cmp eax, ps
        jge quit
        mov ecx, n
    loop2:
        mov eax, [a + ecx*4 - 4]
        cmp eax, 0
        jge next3
        mov [a + ecx*4 - 4], 0
    next3:
        loop loop2

    quit:
    }


    cout << "New array:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << a[i] << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

В `loop1` накапливаем суммы модулей и положительных (переменные `ng` и `ps`). Затем сравниваем, и во втором цикле, если нужно, обнуляем... Сделано для VC++, с другими ассемблерами я не очень знаком...

Comment: код не работает... По крайней мере у меня, мне кажется проблема в адресах элементов массива

Comment: VC++ 2019 (я сразу говорил, что это для данного компилятора), 32-разрядное приложение. Как именно вам показать, что все работает? Копии экрана, или как?

Comment: у меня вроде тоже компилятор 32 разрядный (debug x86), но не работает(

Comment: Еще раз и медленно: что я должен вам предъявить, чтоб вы поняли, что все работает? https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1H6SS75BHm3f3HPkCBmcdRTyeBf6WXtOq?usp=sharing Здесь лежит исходник, результат его компиляции VC++2019 командой `cl /EHsc test.cpp`, запускаемый `exe`, две копии экрана. Вы даже не пишете, что значит "не работает". Я понятия не имею, какую фигню вы наворотили. Если и это вас не устраивает — то, как бы это сказать... Очень мягко — идите и учитесь.

Comment: все работает, большое спасибо!) понял в чем ошибка)

Comment: [Утирая пот со лба] Фуууу... Слава Богу! :)

Answer (score 3):

Ты пишешь "правильно" но "плохо", суть ассемблера в том чтобы действие выполнялось так быстро как это только возможно, иначе нет смысла писать на ассемблере вообще.

```
__asm {
// пушим два нуля и теперь в стеке у нас есть две нулевые переменные
push 0
push 0

// устанавливаем счетчик и сразу декрементируем его на единицу
mov ecx, n
dec ecx

SumMod: 
    mov eax, [a + ecx * dword]  // загружаем число
    mov edx, eax                // копируем число
    neg eax                     // получаем негативное число
    cmovs eax, edx
    // возвращаем в регистр EAX копию числа только при условии что негативное число 
    // отрицательное, таким образом после этой процедуры EAX всегда будет положительным,
    // и как следствие отпадает надобность в условном переходе,
    // функция стала проще, быстрей и наглядней

    bt  edx, 1Fh  // помещаем знаковый бит во флаг переполнения 
    sbb edx, edx
    // вычитаем EDX из самого себя с учетом флага переполнения, и получаем
    // -1 для всех случаев когда число положительно
    // и 0 для всех случаев когда число отрицательно

    add [esp + edx * dword + dword], eax
    // суммируем полученное число с одним из двух значений в стеке,
    // при этом с каким именно определяется значением регистра EDX
    // снова мы "схлопнули" две ветви кода в одну
    dec ecx
jns SumMod

pop eax         // загружаем модуль отрицательных чисел
cmp eax, [esp]  // сравниваем его с модулем положительных чисел
jnc exit        // покидаем процедуру если отрицательный модуль больше

// настраиваем начальные значения цикла
mov ecx, n
xor edx, edx
dec ecx

ReSaveData: 
    mov eax, [a + ecx * dword]  // загружаем число
    test  eax, eax              // тестим его и узнаем его знак
    cmovs eax, edx
    // загружаем в EAX нулевое значение из EDX, если число отрицательно
    // теперь ЕАХ всегда содержит либо положительное число либо ноль

    mov [a + ecx * dword], eax
    dec  ecx
jns ReSaveData

exit:
    pop eax  // восстанавливаем значение стека
}
```

Comment: Хотел понять, насколько это быстрее, чем у @Harry. Не можете дать свой код так, чтоб его было достаточно перенести в VC++, не исправляя? Все эти `@@` для него непонятны.

Comment: Не компилирует - `mov eax, [a + ecx * dword]`, `add [esp + edx * dword + dword], eax`, `mov eax, [a + ecx * dword]`, `mov [a + ecx * dword], eax` - ошибка *error C2400: синтаксическая ошибка во встроенном коде на языке ассемблера*, и в `jnc exit` - *warning C4414: exit: короткий переход к функции преобразован в ближний переход*.

Comment: Я исправил `dword` на 4 и название метки, но при выполнении получил вот такой ввод и вывод: `Your array: -1 5 2 -2 7 2 6 6 0 -1` и `New array:
-1 5 2 0 7 2 6 6 0 0` - то есть первое значение не обнулено.

Comment: Надо поменять JNZ на JNS

Comment: Выдает такую ошибку: Вызвано исключение по адресу 0x00C930E4 в TikhonovD_1944_EVM_lab1_var3.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при исполнении по адресу 0x00C930E4.
Как получить эти права доступа?)

Comment: Такие ошибки характерны при смене адресации. Это 32-х битный код, при переносе его в 64-х битное приложение он будет выдавать ошибку доступа. проверь "разрядность" твоего приложения. Получить такие "права" доступа кстати нельзя, но можно исправить адресацию чтобы не было ошибки.

Comment: не подскажите, а как переписать ваш код под версию х86? у меня можно выбрать 64 и 86 разрядность, но пишет платформа Win32.

Comment: @Sherry Smith Данный код построен вокруг инструкции CMOVXX введенной с Pentium Pro, этот код нельзя переписать под 16 битный код. Вот тебе список всех инструкций и процессоров начиная с которых они валидны https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_instruction_listings